# PHP MYSQL Couldn't execute query: Unknown column

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me to figure out this. The first query would return a message saying that

```
Couldn't execute query: Unknown column 'ssd23' in 'where clause.
```

`ssd23` is the value the `$_POST` will get for the pnumber from a html form. However, it would work if there are only digits.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM Tools WHERE PartNumber = {'$_POST['pnumber']'}") or die ("Couldn't execute query: " .mysqli_error($con));
```

This second query below would work with both digits and characters after using a variable.

```
$test = $_POST['pnumber'];                  
$result = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM Tools WHERE PartNumber = '$test'") or die ("Couldn't execute query: " .mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: There is a SQL injection vulnerability in this code, which will mean that your site will be taken down by crackers in short order. Please don't go live with this code!

Comment: Use prepared statements to pass dynamic input into SQL queries. They are designed specifically to increase security, *and* they will help you avoid this specific problem in the future.

Comment: There is obviously a missing quote around the *value* which is then treated as a *field name*. Amusingly enough, you have involuntary exploited at small extend the SQL injection vulnerability of your own code :D

Comment: Thanks for warning me on the SQL injection. I read a little about it & just got broad the idea. I am learning PHP and building a practice website with a database. Working the SQL interface which will be available after using logging in. :) Thanks Sylvain Leroux for pointing the missing quotes, that kinda answered my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM Tools WHERE PartNumber = {'$_POST['pnumber']'}") or die ("Couldn't execute query: " .mysqli_error($con));
```

With this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM Tools WHERE PartNumber = '" . $_POST['pnumber'] ."'") or die ("Couldn't execute query: " .mysqli_error($con));
```

***Notice I did not take care of sql injection above***

Even better is to use prepare statements that will secure your querys, in your case it will be something like this:

```
$sql= 'DELETE FROM Tools WHERE PartNumber= ?';      

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['pnumber']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi Perry. You've replicated the OP's security vulnerability in your example. If you see `$_POST` or other user input added into a query without escaping or parameterisation, be sure to warn the OP that their code is insecure.

Comment: @halfer, I add now a prepare statement example that is much better then the first option :)

Comment: Great stuff Perry! +1

Comment: Thanks Perry! Google says prepared statement is the way to do it, rather than  mysqli_real_escape_string or whatever I may have come up with :) Been working with online tutorials so far.I am still learning about Procedure & Object Oriented PHP, been mixing both together :(