# SQL Like without column name (using php)

Tags: php, sql

I need to find a result from all columns of a table starting with a specific value, regardless the column and assuming I don't know the columns's name, something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $myTable WHERE AllTheColumns LIKE '{$theValue}%'";
```

I know after the "WHERE" I have to specify the column name, but any other solution will be ok (if exists).

Comment: You could look for about column names in metadata information.

Comment: @todd's answer should get you the required result. However I am wondering why you are trying to do it this way? I think you may have better success refining your process and maybe adjusting your table structure.

Comment: @Dijon I'm trying to optimice my code because i'm working with tables with 15 - 23 columns, using the @ яша method.

Answer (score 2):

There's any other way you can do it.

```
SELECT * FROM $myTable 
    WHERE Column1 LIKE '%$search%' 
        OR Column2 LIKE '%$search%' 
        OR Column2 LIKE '%$search%'  
        OR Column3 LIKE '%$search%'
```

Comment: yes I know that way, but if I don't know columns's name?

Comment: unfotunately it is not possible unless you dig into your DB metadata

Answer (score 2):

You could first select all the column names from the table:

`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';`

// store resulting column names in $column_names var;

Then, with an array of column names, create a loop that adds each column name to the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE ";

foreach($column_names as $i => $colname) {
  $query .= "$colname LIKE %$search_string% ";
  if ($i+1 < $column_names.length()) {
    $query .= " OR ";
  }
}

// do stuff with query
```

Comment: I trying this way but I think I'm not creating correctly that array of column names, I have this: $sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'personal';"; $thenames = mysql_query($sql, $db); $column_names=array(); while($fila = mysql_fetch_object($thenames)) { array_push($column_names,$fila); } and the error: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\ ...

Answer (score 1):

possibly, there are two options.

**1) You can get all column names and perform operation accordingly.**

- Possible Solution:
  [MySQL query to get column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)

**2) You can reffere specific column by typing index.**

- Possible solution:
  [Getting a Mysql Results without knowing a column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035490/getting-a-mysql-results-without-knowing-a-column-name)